# How to correctly delete NSManagedObject relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have the following entities and relationship:

Entity0,
EntityA,
EntityB,
EntityC

Entity0 can have 0 or many EntityA(s).
EntityA has a one-to-one relationship "entityB" with EntityB (inverse is "itemB").
EntityC has a many-to-many relationship "entityBs" with EntityB (inverse is "itemCs").
The delete rule for all relationships is "Nullify".

I created one EntityA and tied one EntityB to it.
Then I created one EntityC and tied that EntityB to it.

During delete of EntityA, I do this...

```
self.entityA.entityB = nil;
[self.entity0 removeEntityAObject:self.entityA];
```

Now, I was expecting the "entityBs" tied to EntityC will be deleted as well.  However, when I tried to get the details of "entityBs" from EntityC

```
NSLog(@"details %@", self.entityC.entityBs);
```

I got this error on first call:

```
entityBs = "<relationship fault: 0x1557abb0 'entityBs'>";
```

Then I tap the back button and select again the EntityC to retrieve the details once more.  Then I got this:

```
entityBs =     (
    "0x1669b8b0 <x-coredata://12REF41B-4A7D-4A51-B6BC-2RHRI5DC3124/EntityB/p22>"
);
status = 0;
}) with objects {(
<EntityB: 0x166ac100> (entity: EntityB; id: 0x1669b8b0 <x-coredata://12REF41B-4A7D-4A51-B6BC-2RHRI5DC3124/EntityB/p22> ; data: <fault>)
```

It is as if the entityB is still there.
How should I correctly perform deletion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The B entity is still there because you have set the deletion rules to nullify (and you didn't actually delete anything, you just removed a reference). To have the B entity deleted you would need to do 3 things:

1. Set the delete rule for the relationship from A to B to cascade
2. Not `nil` the reference to B (from A)
3. Actually delete A from the context

Comment: For #3, do you mean doing [self.entity0 removeEntityAObject:self.entityA]; and calling [self.managedObjectContext save:&error] is not enough to delete entityA from the context?... then how should I delete entityA from the context?

Comment: or before I call on save, I need to specifically delete entityA from context... [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:self.entityA];?

Comment: You need to call `deleteObject:`

Comment: `removeEntityAObject:` just removes from the relationship, not the context

Comment: ohhh... this is what i was looking for a long time... cause i've been having issue deleting and removing relationship references... all this time i thought i don't need to call deleteObject on a child entity :)... thanks a lot for your help

Comment: but do i need to call removeEntityAObject: before deleteObject:?... or calling deleteObject: will remove entityA from entity0 since it's relationship is nullify?

Comment: Deleting will be enough, that is what the deletion rules are for.